# Consulta MYSQL con una condicion de varios ids

Tags: php, mysql

estoy tratando de entender como podria hacer una condiccion que  a partir de un **WHERE** me imprima todo menos las publicaciones con los ids que hay en un array llamado **$dataP** ejemplo:

```
$dataP=[];//los ids se guardaran aqui

$sql=$con->query("SELECT * FROM nacionales ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 10");

 while($rowP=$sql->fetch_array()){

   array_push($dataP, $rowP['id']);

 }
```

Mas adelante en mi pagina nececito imprimir unos **Posts** de la misma tabla donde los ids no sean iguales a los que ya estan en el array, Ejemplo:

```
$query1=$con->query("SELECT * FROM nacionales ORDER BY fecha DESC WHERE ids no sean iguales a los que estan en el array $dataP");
```

Como podria hacer esto no tengo ni idea, gracias ojala puedan ayudarme!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar NOT IN() de Mysql

```
// une los Ids del array a un string de ids separados por coma
$ids = implode(",", $dataP);

$query1=$con->query("SELECT * FROM nacionales WHERE id NOT IN($ids) ORDER BY fecha DESC");
```

Comment: Genial! gracias